# how to fix opt parse optparse.OptionError: invalid long option string '-submitted.cl': must start with --, followed by non-dash

Tags: python, optparse

I have the following options using OptionParser

```
parser = OptionParser()
parser.add_option("-submitted.cl", "--change_list", dest="change_list",help="Submitted Change list")
parser.add_option("-submitted.cr", "--crlist", dest="cr_list",help="Submitted CR list")
parser.add_option("-build.location", "--sbl", dest="sbl",help="Source build location")
parser.add_option("-filer.location", "--dbl", dest="dbl",help="Filer location")
parser.add_option("-users", "--users",dest="users",help="Users")
(options, args) = parser.parse_args()
```

I am running the script  using following options and running into following error, Please provide inputs on how to fix it.

```
python save_build_artifacts.py 12345 02384 \\ben\cnss_dev_integration\nfc_builds\LA_host_builds\8084\Build2  \\ben\cnss_dev_integration\temp gnakkala
```

ERROR:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "save_build_artifacts.py", line 75, in <module>
    main()
  File "save_build_artifacts.py", line 43, in main
    parser.add_option("-submitted.cl", "--change_list", dest="change_list",help="Submitted Change list")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\optparse.py", line 1012, in add_option
    option = self.option_class(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\optparse.py", line 566, in __init__
    self._set_opt_strings(opts)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\optparse.py", line 606, in _set_opt_strings
    self)
optparse.OptionError: invalid long option string '-submitted.cl': must start with --, followed by non-dash
```

Comment: what is your python version, Optparse has been deprecated in python-2.7. Try using argparse. http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#module-argparse

Answer (score 7):

The first parameter in `parser.add_option` is for a short parameter. `-submitted.cl` is too long, since short parameter are one character long. So try something like

```
from optparse import OptionParser

parser = OptionParser()
parser.add_option("-c", "--change_list", dest="change_list",help="Submitted Change list")
parser.add_option("-r", "--crlist", dest="cr_list",help="Submitted CR list")
parser.add_option("-b", "--sbl", dest="sbl",help="Source build location")
parser.add_option("-f", "--dbl", dest="dbl",help="Filer location")
parser.add_option("-u", "--users",dest="users",help="Users")
(options, args) = parser.parse_args()
```

Also in your invocation you need to name the parameters you are using like `python save_build_artifacts.py 23 43 -c file.xy`

Have a look at [this doc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html) for examples.

(And consider using argparse instead. Optparse is deprecated)